# Why do I get invalid unsported format character ' ' error when I don't have any ' ' character in parameter names?

Tags: django

I am trying to create a json schema and validate it using the standard validation base class. I get this error message which I can't tell what it refers to exactly.
[image]

Looking at my schema and value I don't see anywhere where I have an empty space in the parameter names and I'm not sure what the index 38 reffers to.

The schema that I provide is:

```
# value = {'enabled': -1, 'order_index': 0, 'width': 10}
# schema = {
    'title': 'The Test column schema', 
    'type': 'object', 
    'required': ['enabled', 'order_index', 'width'],
    'default': {'enabled': True, 'order_index': 0, 'width': 10},
    'properties':
        {'enabled':
            {'title': 'Enabled',
             'description': 'Display of column',
             'type': 'boolean'
            },
         'order_index':
            {'title': 'Order Index',
             'description': 'Order of column to be displayed',
             'type': 'number',
             'minimum': 0,
             'maximum': 999,
             'default': 0
            },
         'width': 
            {'title': 'Width',
             'description': 'Width of column to be displayed', 
             'type': 'number',
             'minimum': 10,
             'maximum': 999, 
             'default': 30}}}
        
validate_schema = JSONSchemaValidator(limit_value=schema)
validate_schema(value)
```

Where JSONSchemaValidator is an inheritor of the Django.BaseValidator

```
class JSONSchemaValidator(BaseValidator):
def compare(self, a, b):
    try:
        jsonschema.validate(a, b)
    except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as e:
        raise ValidationError(
            "Failed JSON schema check for %(value). {}".format(str(e)), params={"value": a}
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out my error was not in my code but an exception in django failing to format a string.

Comment: This wasn't true either. Turn out I made a change that broke the custom JSONValidator but the error was throuwn inside the BaseValidator from Django which got me confused.